# Select checkbox multiple by custom attribute and get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a project to learn something.
I have a booking system that books movies seats.
It is all well done, but now I want to put a custom value on a checkbox and when it is checked I want to get the value from that attribute and I want to pass it into an ajax request.  Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#frmRezerva").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         var $fields = $(this).find('input[name="scaun_film[]"]:checked');
         if (!$fields.length) {
            alert('Selectati un scaun sau mai multe!');
                return false; 
        }
        var arr=[];
             $.each($("input[name='scaun_film[]']:checked"), function(){            
                    arr.push($(this).val());
            });

             //console.log(arr)
        $("#mail-status3").hide();
        $('#rezBtn').hide();
        $('#loader-icon3').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "rezervare.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
            "arr": arr,
            "id_movie":$('input[name="id_movie"]').val(),
            "nume_film":$('input[name="nume_film"]').val(),
            "gen_film":$('input[name="nume_film"]').val(),
            "nota_film":$('input[name="nota_film"]').val(),
            "user_id":$('input[name="user_id"]').val(),
            "user_email":$('input[name="user_email"]').val(),
            "data_film":$('select[name="data_film"]').val(),
            "bilete_film":$('input[name="bilete_film"]').val(),
            "cinematograf":$('select[name="cinematograf"]').val()},             
            success: function(response){
                window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000)
            $("#mail-status3").show();
            $('#loader-icon3').hide();
            if(response.type == "error") {
                $('#rezBtn').show();
                $("#mail-status3").attr("class","alert alert-danger");               
            } else if(response.type == "message"){
                $('#rezBtn').show();
                $("#mail-status3").attr("class","alert alert-success");                          
            }
            $("#mail-status3").html(response.text);  
            },
            error: function(){} 
        });
    }));
});
</script>
```

Here is my jquery where i select if the checkbox was checked. I can get the value but I want the same thing but only from  a custom attribute. My custom attribute is seatName with a value from the database.
EDIT: html here is :

```
<?php 
                    $sqlsq = "SELECT * FROM scaune WHERE id_scaun_movie='{$_GET['id_movie']}'";
                    $resultsq = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlsq);
                    while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsq)){?>

<?php if($rs['ocupat'] == 1){?>
    <div class="box">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$rs['id'];?>" disabled checked><span class="label-text"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <?php }else{?>
        <div class="box">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$rs['id'];?>" seatName="<?=$rs['scaun'];?>" name="scaun_film[]"><span class="label-text"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>
```

So what i need to do is to select chair name and id of that chair to update in mysql rezerved, but i dont find a solution to get id and name of chair when is checked also i need to be more than 1 so if is checked 3 chairs to get all name seats checked. Thanks!

Comment: but what does your HTML look like? One way to put custom values on a control is to use `data-` attributes, which can be fetched with jQuery by doing `element.data('somename')` which would fetch the value of the attribute `data-somename="somevalue"` - That is, if your custom attribute is like `seatName="5A"` you'd be better off changing that to `data-seatname="5A"`

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of your fetching the values for other fields:

```
"id_movie":$('input[name="id_movie"]').val()
```

You can probably do it like:

```
"seat_name":$('input[name="seat_name"]').data('seatName'),
```

<del>But you don't show any of your page structure / markup so this is at best a suggestion.</del>

This would work if your element looked something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seat_name" value="something" data-seatName="5A">
```

Using custom `data-` attributes is preferred over making up your own attributes, such as
`<input type="checkbox" seatName="5A">`
is better with the data- prefix
`<input type="checkbox" data-seatName="5A">`

---

**EDIT**

The HTML/PHP you posted:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?=$rs['id'];?>" seatName="<?=$rs['scaun'];?>"
       name="scaun_film[]"><span class="label-text"></span>
```

Could simply be re-done as:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?=$rs['id'];?>" data-seatName="<?=$rs['scaun'];?>"
       name="scaun_film[]"><span class="label-text"></span>
```

Then fetching the data would work as I said above, and you would add it to the data you're sending in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "rezervare.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
        "arr": arr,
        "id_movie":$('input[name="id_movie"]').val(),
        "nume_film":$('input[name="nume_film"]').val(),
        "gen_film":$('input[name="nume_film"]').val(),
        "nota_film":$('input[name="nota_film"]').val(),
        "seat_name":$('input[name="seat_name"]').data('seatName'), /* ADD */
        "user_id":$('input[name="user_id"]').val(),
        /* etc. */
```

Comment: I put also html

Comment: Can i put as array because he can select more than 1 seats

Comment: here is my php what i try it `$seat_name = $_POST['seat_name'];`  i use what you give to me and i dont know how i can get values from that attribute.

Comment: Inside of my php file how i can receive values like this > `$seat_name = $_POST['seat_name'];` ?

Comment: @Edward - I don't really know PHP, but `$_POST['seat_name']` seems like what I've seen before.  It should work whatever way you currently use to get the other values, like `user_id` and `id_movie`.